# I'm trying to use an aggregate function in order to consolidate the data but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find the total price per unit quantity and price. How can I make this work in a way where I can consolidate all the orders from one person with the total price that they ordered?

I'm new to SQL and not sure where to start to fix this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.OrderID, Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderDate, [Order 
Details].Quantity * [Order Details].UnitPrice
FROM Orders, Customers, [Order Details]
WHERE Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
AND Orders.ShipCountry = 'Spain'
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Can you provide example input and output?

Comment: How do you join `[order details]` with `[orders]` table?

Comment: 10281 Alejandra Camino 1996-08-14 00:00:00.000 500.00
10281 Alejandra Camino 1996-08-14 00:00:00.000 378.00
10281 Alejandra Camino 1996-08-14 00:00:00.000 1000.00            
              This is an example output when I run this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three important things I can advice you to do:

1. Use explicit `JOIN` syntax: don't write your tables separately with comma, use explicit JOINs against them so it forces you to write their link at that moment and it's easier to read later. Your attempt was missing a link between the orders and the order details, probably making a lot of duplicates on your results.
2. Aggregates needs a `GROUP BY`. Whenever you want to apply aggregate functions like `SUM`, `MAX`, `COUNT`, you will (mostly) need a set of columns you want to group together. These columns go in the `GROUP BY` clause.
3. Don't use `DISTINCT` if you are unsure of the results you are getting. It seems that you used `DISTINCT` to cover up the missing link between orders and order details, so it just list uniques instead of the actual data your select is returning.

   ```
   SELECT 
       C.CustomerID,
       C.ContactName,
       O.OrderID,
       O.OrderDate,
       TotalPrice = SUM(D.Quantity * D.UnitPrice)
   FROM 
       Orders AS O
       INNER JOIN Customers AS C ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
       INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID
   WHERE 
       O.ShipCountry = 'Spain'
   GROUP BY
       C.CustomerID,
       C.ContactName,
       O.OrderID,
       O.OrderDate
   ```

Comment: Thank you again. I didn't realize that I could shorten the columns like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the join like this...

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Orders.OrderID, Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderDate, 
    [Order Details].Quantity * [Order Details].UnitPrice FROM Orders left join 
    Customers on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID left join [Order 
    Details] on Orders.CustomerID = [Order Details].CustomerID where 
    Orders.ShipCountry = 'Spain'
```

Comment: [order details] is not an alias but a separate table. Please check the question again.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Orders.OrderID, Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderDate, [Order 
    Details].Quantity * [Order Details].UnitPrice
    FROM Orders
    left join Customers
    on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
   left join  [Order Details] on   Orders.CustomerID = [Order Details].CustomerID 
  where Orders.ShipCountry = 'Spain

Comment: I'm not the OP, and you should update your answer; as well as read through the latest comment on question by OP.